# Wrong ifft in numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, fft

I have this bidimensional array called a:

```
[2.1814 + 0.0000i   1.1375 + 0.0000i   0.2506 + 0.0000i   0.2506 + 0.0000i   1.1375 + 0.0000i]
[-2.1719 + 0.2033i  -1.1326 + 0.1060i  -0.2496 + 0.0234i  -0.2496 + 0.0234i  -1.1326 + 0.1060i]
[2.0884 + 0.6302i   1.0890 + 0.3286i   0.2400 + 0.0724i   0.2400 + 0.0724i   1.0890 + 0.3286i]
[1.8018 + 1.2295i   0.9396 + 0.6412i   0.2070 + 0.1413i   0.2070 + 0.1413i   0.9396 + 0.6412i]
```

When I run ifft(a) in matlab it gives me this answer:

```
[0.9749 + 0.5158i   0.5084 + 0.2690i   0.1120 + 0.0593i   0.1120 + 0.0593i   0.5084 + 0.2690i]
[0.2798 - 1.1510i   0.1459 - 0.6002i   0.0322 - 0.1323i   0.0322 - 0.1323i   0.1459 - 0.6002i]
[1.1599 - 0.2007i   0.6049 - 0.1046i   0.1333 - 0.0231i   0.1333 - 0.0231i   0.6049 - 0.1046i]
[-0.2333 + 0.8359i  -0.1217 + 0.4359i  -0.0268 + 0.0960i  -0.0268 + 0.0960i  -0.1217 + 0.4359i]
```

When I run np.fft.ifft2(a) in python it gives me this answer

```
[[ 0.44314676+0.23444054j  0.22157338+0.11722027j  0.04431468+0.02344405j 0.04431468+0.02344405j  0.22157338+0.11722027j]
 [ 0.12718937-0.52317671j  0.06359468-0.26158836j  0.01271894-0.05231767j 0.01271894-0.05231767j  0.06359468-0.26158836j]
 [ 0.52724743-0.09120678j  0.26362372-0.04560339j  0.05272474-0.00912068j 0.05272474-0.00912068j  0.26362372-0.04560339j]
 [-0.10604754+0.37994295j -0.05302377+0.18997148j -0.01060475+0.0379943j -0.01060475+0.0379943j  -0.05302377+0.18997148j]]
```

Why is it different? How can I make both python and matlab give me the same answer?

Comment: Please read [mre]. If the answer below doesn’t solve your problem, we can’t be sure of what you did, so can’t point out what you’re doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you should use ifft2 in MATLAB, or np.fft.ifft in numpy.

ifft2 is two-dimensional inverse discrete Fourier Transform, and ifft is one-dimensional. These are two different algorithms and they lead to different answers.

Comment: I also tried to use np.fft.ifft and the outputs are still different from matlab's ifft outputs.

From what I tested, the functions fft, fft2 and fftn from Numpy are equivalents to Matlab's fft. However, when it comes to inverse fast fourier transform, none of the Numpy's functions ifft, ifft2 and ifftn results in the same outputs as matlab's ifft

Comment: @rodrigomachado fft, fft2 and fftn from Python are equivalent to the functions of the same names from MATLAB. In no way is MATLAB’s fft equivalent to Python’s fft2 or fftn.

Comment: @rodrigomachado I also tested it and found that ifft and np.fft.ifft gave out the almost same outputs. Perhaps something went wrong in your test code.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that in the fft function the default axis = -1, when I put axis = 0, the code generated the same value as the matlab